# Find part of string throughout site and replace with new text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still having trouble understanding regex.  I am also not even sure if you can target a whole page...but without knowledge of how to format regex, its getting play with it.

I have a trademarked name that appears throughout my page.  I'd like to use JS to add a (r) to the end of it every time it appears.

Can jquery/js accomplish this?

```
$("body").each(function() {
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(
               'breathe right', 
               'breathe right(r)');
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, `document.body`.

Comment: Try and see by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use case for the CSS `:after` pseudo-element:

**CSS**

```
.product-name:after {
    content: " \00AE"; /* add restricted symbol after every element with the product-name class */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="product-name">My Product</span>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6DTr4/)**

The easiest way is to wrap your product name in a span and tag it with a class. I'm not sure if that's less work that just adding the symbol to your markup to begin with, though.

The benefit of this approach is it would allow you to easily apply other styles to your product name, like bolding the text or changing the font color.

You can read more about the `:after` pseudo-element [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter).

Comment: Im going to mark this as correct.  Unfortunately, it doesnt work in my case because I am forced to use an awkward CMS that uses the title input to display menu items in Nav.  Which means, I'd have to add <span> tags into the title input field...which is confusing for people who are using CMS's

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it won't be efficient if you tell jQuery to search the entire document. To make it efficient, you'll need to have jQuery get a specific location to search if you want any efficiency in it.

Comment: I figured that might be the case...I'll do something else.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery :

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/breathe right/g, 'breathe right(r)')
```